# Gulp Concat no output file

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, gulp

I am trying to concatinate my js files with gulp's concate module.

My projects path to js files is: `project/public/js/vendor/`.

In vendor are all the plugins I use and I want to concatinate them to a single file

I use the following code to execute my task.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('scripts',function(){
    return gulp.src('./vendor/*.js')
        .pipe(concat('global.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('concat/'));

});

gulp.task('default', ['scripts']);
```

I want to export the file to concat folder which is located into /js, but I get no file.
The code executes with no error report.

```
[gulp] Using gulpfile /var/www/vhosts/site.dev/httpdocs/project/gulpfile.js
[gulp] Starting 'scripts'...
[gulp] Finished 'scripts' after 9.2 ms
[gulp] Starting 'default'...
[gulp] Finished 'default' after 8.8 μs
```

Did I do something wrong?

**Edit 1**

I tried to log the count as it was suggested and returned:

```
[gulp] Using gulpfile /var/www/vhosts/site.dev/httpdocs/laravel/gulpfile.js
[gulp] Starting 'scripts'...
[gulp] Finished 'scripts' after 12 ms
[gulp] Starting 'default'...
[gulp] Finished 'default' after 9.37 μs
```

Does this means that it didn't select any js?

Comment: some clearifications please: "concat folder which is located into /js" - can you please explain the folder structure? both for the src and the dest
Did you check if the files global.js is present in ./vendor/ ?

Comment: From the current info... can it be that you just need to use gulp.dest('./concat/')?

Comment: Thatkookooguy: I checked vendor I didn't find the required file, also concat folrder is in general js folder named "js" and is empy, vendor is inside the same folder and containes some .js files.

Comment: did you try what I suggested in my second comment?
Also, it's better to edit your question and include the new data than write it in a comment.

Answer (score 5):

mostly there are not source files being selected, use gulp-count to print the number of files selected

```
var count = require('gulp-count');

gulp.task('scripts',function(){
    return gulp.src('./vendor/*.js')
        .pipe(count('## js-files selected'))
        .pipe(concat('global.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('concat/'));

});
```

if you get count as 0, given your path is `project/public/js/vendor/` change your `gulp.src` to `gulp.src('project/public/js/vendor/**/*.js')`

Answer (score 0):

it might be related with the place where you are running your gulpfile. You're saying the path for your files are at:

```
 project/public/js/vendor
```

but your gulpfile is running at

```
project/gulpfile
```

so gulp is not finding any file at:

```
./vendor/*.js
```

and that's because the path might be getting resolved to:

```
project/vendor/*.js
```

What you should do is:

1. Try using as path for the files **./public/vendor/*.js**
2. If it doesn't work, you need to know where your working directory is, to know this log where you're:

   ```
    cosole.log(__dirname)
   ```
3. Then you can either use that working directory for your path or you can path the working directory as input to the task and then do something like:

   ```
    const path = require('path);

    ...

    let jspath = path.join(basePathInput, 'public/vendor/*.js')
    return gulp.src(jspath).
           ....
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue now and in my case, the cause was simply a syntactic error in one of the files.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the answers and in my case it was simply the fact that I had hooked it too soon into the gulp lifecycle and therefor build / my file was overwritten afterwards.

So if everything from the other answers is okay have a look into your lifecycle hooks.